# Why am I getting file not found exception?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I have text files imported into my java project folder through eclipse. I am trying to load up the texts which contains a dictionary of random words, go through them and create a hashmap with the first letter of the words being the key and the word as a whole being the value.

I have a method in a class WordStore:

```
public WordStore(String k) throws IOException {
    map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    BufferedReader buffread = null;
    File filename = null;
    FileReader fread = null;
    try{
        filename = new File(k);
        fread = new FileReader(filename);
        buffread = new BufferedReader(fread);   
        String word ="";

        while((word = buffread.readLine()) != null) {
            if(word.length()<3) {
            //don't add word less than 3 characters long
            }
            else {
                String key = ""+(word.charAt(0));
                put(key, word);
            }

        }

    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found exception caught!");
    }
    finally {
        if(buffread != null) {
            try {
                buffread.close();
            }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

}
```

I use it in the class WordStoreTest:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class WordStoreTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WordStore store = new WordStore("nouns.txt");
    System.out.println(store.getRandomWord("b"));

}

}
```

Exception:

```
File not found exception caught! java.io.FileNotFoundException: nouns.txt (No such file or directory
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195
 at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138
 at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:72
 at WordStore.(WordStore.java:34
 at WordStoreTest.main(WordStoreTest.java:14) null
```

[image]

Comment: post the stacktrace please

Comment: how can I do that? When I run it through eclipse, it simply prints "File not found exception caught!" from System.out.println("File not found exception caught!")

Comment: for stacktrace `e.printStackTrace();` line must be in first catch block.

Comment: File not found exception caught!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: nouns.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
 at WordStore.<init>(WordStore.java:34)
 at WordStoreTest.main(WordStoreTest.java:14)
null

Comment: The path is clearly wrong.  You assume that Eclipse is smart enough to look in your project root.  The stack trace will make it clear.

Comment: The stack trace as written above: File not found exception caught! java.io.FileNotFoundException: nouns.txt (No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72) at WordStore.<init>(WordStore.java:34) at WordStoreTest.main(WordStoreTest.java:14) null

Comment: where is the `txt` file in comparison to your project root ? Or otherwise said - what is the project structure ?

Comment: all my classes/java files as well as the txt files are within the src file in my project folder

Comment: I assume you mean the txt files are in the `src` folder ` ? then it is `src/nouns.txt`. The path starts always from the root of the project

Comment: Put the trace in THE POST and not in comment , also what about if 2 words start with same letter ? Because key is unique in map

Comment: @azro I have a get random method which picks a random word if there is more than one word with the same letter.

Comment: @EmersonCod your assumption is correct yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting a `BufferedReader` from a `File`, I always use an `InputStream`. As an example, you could do this:

```
String path = "/nouns.txt";
try {
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/misc/sample.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));


    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    for(; line!=null; line=bufferedReader.readLine()) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }


    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course, the path here assumes that your `txt` files are under `src` and not a package, but you could always change that. You could even create a second source folder and put it inside of there.

Answer (score 0):

To access a file that is inside your project structure, you need to re-create the path from the project root to the file itself.

Assuming the file resides in the `src` folder, like

```
PROJECT
 |
  src
   |
    nouns.txt
    aPackage
      |
       Main.java
```

Then following code is successful:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(Files.exists(Paths.get("src", "nouns.txt")));
 }
}
```